# Offset Path when drawing arrow

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm drawing a arrow, by doing the following:

```
deltaX = this.mPoints[1].x - this.mPoints[3].x;
deltaY = this.mPoints[1].y - this.mPoints[3].y;

frac = (float) 0.1;

point_x_1 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY;
point_y_1 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX;

point_x_2 = this.mPoints[1].x;
point_y_2 = this.mPoints[1].y;

point_x_3 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY;
point_y_3 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX;

Path path = new Path();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
path.moveTo(point_x_1,  point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);

path.close();

canvas.drawLine(this.mPoints[3].x, this.mPoints[3].y, this.mPoints[1].x, this.mPoints[1].y, this.mPaint);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

This is the result I get:

[image: arrow image]

As you can see the line that I draw sticks out behind the arrow head.

**My Question:**

How can i modify what I currently have to avoid the line from being seen behind the arrow head.

I have tried `path.offset(-30,30);` with various values, but it didn't work as the angle of the line will change each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the line to end at 90% of the current drawn line (this is `1 - frac`, so the line should end at the bottom of the arrow triangle):

```
deltaX = this.mPoints[1].x - this.mPoints[3].x;
deltaY = this.mPoints[1].y - this.mPoints[3].y;

frac = (float) 0.1;

point_x_1 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY;
point_y_1 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX;

point_x_2 = this.mPoints[1].x;
point_y_2 = this.mPoints[1].y;

point_x_3 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY;
point_y_3 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX;

line_end_x = this.mPoints[1].x - frac * deltaX; // This
line_end_y = this.mPoints[1].y - frac * deltaY;

Path path = new Path();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
path.moveTo(point_x_1,  point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);

path.close();

// line_end_* instead of this.mPoints[1].*
canvas.drawLine(this.mPoints[3].x, this.mPoints[3].y, line_end_x, line_end_y, this.mPaint);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

I've been unable to test the maths, but I think it's correct. Give it a try.